# The configuration in win 7 for Apache 2.2 + php 5.2

Tags: php, apache

Every time I start apache , it always fails.
The problem is in loadmodulephp5...
The error log:[warn] pid file C:/windows/Apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten — Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run? 
I tried to delete this file and then start apache.But this file had been created again.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try **not installing apache into OS directory**. Or even better, just use xampp / wamp / zend server / whatever.

Comment: I tried.Unfortunately still useless.
The log:[warn] pid file D:/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten
But still thanks for you.I haven't installed zend server.Win 2008 server may make it better.